# What is the best datatype in MySQL for unexpected value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, time-series

i do api for big data. In principally, every minute i get a lot of values. Its some measurands of electrical energy. It could be a float (802.6522) or array of variable length, but value in array is in interval <0;1> [1,0,0,0,0,1, ...]. Every minute i have got a 23 000 rows!
I dont no, what is best structure of my database table.
First version is:

```
id (int) | created_at (timestamp)| value (text) | measurand_id (int) | is_array (tinyint)
```

every value is convert to json, and if the value is array, column "is_array" is 1, else 0. But this method is taking lot of memory size in DB. I built this because -  every day, i merge values for one measurand and save as one array to another table (one records in first table is deleted):

```
id (int) | created_at (timestamp) | measurand_id (int) | value_for_one_day( text)
```

value_for_one_day is `pack("d*", ...[802.2555, 803.2555, ...]`

I think about creating two tables, one for float data, second for binary. But i still have a bad feeling about this. Solution must be fast and effective.

So, is there anyone, who have a some skills about saving a timeseries to MySQL? Thank you very much, and sorry for my english.

Comment: personally I would consider using a noSql db for this such as elastic search, that way you wouldn't have to worry about the data type as long as you can convert it to JSON. Afterwards if I still found a Sql db necessary for my use case I would use the noSql db as queue so that I could properly parse and covert the data at my own pace in the background.

Comment: Big data is, well, big.  23K row per minute is about 33M rows per day.  In the world of big data, 33M is not all that big.  What problem, exactly, are you having other than a concern in your head that it is "taking lot of memory size".

Comment: My probelm isnt a big data, but what is the best datatype, when i can get a float or binary array :)